# UIScrollView Best Practices with hundreds of data points

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Microsoft Outlook used to have - and maybe still does - a scrolling timeline view of all activity that has taken place within outlook. I'd like to recreate something like that in my app.

I have studied the documentation for UIScrollView, and I know how to make it work the way I want. My question is more geared towards to most efficient way to present several hundred items in a UIScrollView when the content view is likely to be large.

I could:

- Assemble a list of smaller views, each representing a day, for example, and populate those smaller views with the data items from each of those days and then append those aggregate views as sub views into the content view.

or

- I could just simply populate a content view with sub views for each of the data items I want to display on the timeline.

What I'm looking to find out is:

1. What's the most efficient way, from a memory and time perspective, to present all these data points? Each will appear on the timeline as a label or button.
2. Which method would more naturally support pinching and zooming?
3. Is it better to initialize the entire content view ahead of time (and possibly take a big time penalty), or is it better to just initialize the view in the vicinity of the 'view window' and then add in details as the user scrolls around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you'll know for sure is by experimenting a bit. I realise that's not an overly helpful answer, but I can at least give you some hints:

Efficiently displaying more than one screenful of stuff with `UIScrollView`s is notoriously difficult. I've struggled with this for weeks in some cases. This was much worse on older hardware (iPhone 3G/2nd gen iPod or older) but you can still easily bring modern iOS devices to a crawl if you get it wrong. You will typically run into two performance issues:

- Having many `UIView`s (this includes UILabel etc.) on screen at once severely hurts performance. You'll run into this if every data point is a view and you can zoom out to see all of them.
- Conversely, having huge views (bigger than one screenful) is equally bad, as the whole view will need to be kept in memory while any of it is visible.

You can probably see how this fits badly with zooming: you don't know exactly how much one screenful is!

- I suggest you set things up nice and simple with everything as views to begin with and don't worry too much about zooming - make sure it all works smoothly at the max zoom level.
- Then, add in zooming (you'll need to put all your little views in one container view which will be zoomed) and see how it performs on your oldest supported hardware. If you don't allow zooming out too far, you may be okay without any change.
- If it starts chugging when you zoom out, try subdividing your content into tiles. You'll need to experiment with the size of these, but 20+ subviews per tile is probably a good start. In your scroll view delegate, detect when the user is sufficiently zoomed out and force your tiles to rasterise by setting the `shouldRasterize` property to true on their `CALayer`. This should essentially pre-render all the subviews of a tiles into a texture, so when it comes to rendering the screen, it'll use that pre-rendered image instead of walking through all your subviews and rendering them individually. Make sure to disable it again once the user zooms in again sufficiently. Also try to avoid setting it for all tiles at once or it will stutter, so for example you could set up separate random zoom level thresholds for each tile.

If you end up having trouble with `shouldRasterize`, you may need to work at the `CALayer` level directly. If none of this helps, the sledgehammer method is to use `CATiledLayer` like the `MKMapView` and others do. This requires you to do all the rendering and touch event handling yourself, and will normally also cause the (somewhat ugly) fade-in you get when scrolling in the Maps and Safari apps.

Some additional hints:

- Avoid keeping lots of different images in memory. This means re-using a small number of `UIImage`s if you can. If each view is slightly different, generate the images on-demand in drawRect: or using filters rather than drawing them as `CGImage`s up front, or loading them from file.
- Avoid alpha blending (translucency) if at all possible.
- You can visualise UIKit compositing complexity using the Performance Tool. Check out the Core Animation and tools talks from the WWDC archives.

I hope that helps you get started. Good luck!

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic information, and just what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the well written answer.